# Why don't I need a certificate to connect to our AWS database?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, ssl-certificate, database-administration

I'm a developer more than a devops or sysadmin. person and I'm trying to work out what we have to do about SSL certificates and our AWS databases.  It is well-known that the certificates issued in 2015 for AWS databases will expire on 5 March 2020 and it is necessary to install the certificates issued in 2019.

However, it seems to me that we don't need certificates to connect to our AWS database.  What I mean by that is that to connect to one of our **Azure** databases, the following *nix command is required:

> mysql -h ourstuff.database.azure.com -u ouruser -p --ssl-ca=certificatefile.crt.pem --ssl-mode=VERIFY_CA

but to connect to our AWS database, we don't need that SSL stuff:

> mysql -h ourstuff.blahblahblah.rds.amazonaws.com --database=ourdatabase -u ouruser -p

Similarly, we have PHP applications that supply the certificate to connect to the Azure database (via `mysqli_ssl_set()`) but not for AWS.

So I have these questions:

- Since there is no option in the AWS dashboard for *removing* the certificate from the database, how is it that I can connect to the database without supplying any credentials?  (other than a password)  Is it because I am on a my company's network, and the network is whitelisted?
- What should I do to force clients to supply credentials?  Empty the IP whitelist table?  If a such thing exists.
- If access is based on IP whitelisting, would it really increase the security of the database if we mandated access via SSL?
- If a certificate isn't required now, owing to the connecting username (as per Mlu's answer below), will that change when I install the 2019 certificates?

Thanks in expectation.

Comment: Answer to my fourth question:  no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be configured per-user in MySQL.

```
ALTER USER '{masteruser}'@'%' REQUIRE SSL;
```

See the [`ALTER USER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-user.html) documentation and look for `REQUIRE SSL`.